# How to View Readme in VS Preview as well as TFS Welcome Page

Tags: git, tfs, visual-studio-2015, markdown, readme

When I create a project with Team Foundation Server and Visual Studio, a `README.md` is automatically generated and placed in the top-level of the project folder (in the same folder as the `.sln`)

This is great, as it allows me to display said readme on the project's **Welcome** page:

[image]

However, this means that when I open this project in Visual Studio, I cannot see the readme, as Solution Explorer scopes to the folder *below* the solution:

[image]

This is not ideal, as it means that I cannot preview the readme in Visual Studio using the Markdown preview extension.

My question is: **Is there some way of having the readme in one location such that I can preview it both on TFS and in Visual Studio?** Please note that although I am using TFS to host my repositories, I am using **Git** for source control instead of Team Foundation Server Version Control.

What I have already tried:

1. As seen in the 2nd screenshot above, I added a `teatreadme.md` to the project folder in the hopes that I could then add that to the welcome page on TFS, however I cannot see such an option.
2. I tried scoping to the top-level folder in Visual Studio, but this is not allowed
3. Selected Show All Files' in Solution Explorer, but this does not reveal `README.md`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You just need to add a `Readme.md` file in the **root of you source control** with your team project.

[image]

Then you should view the  file in **source control explorer** instead of solution explorer. You can also preview the *readme* both in Visual Studio with the extenstion and tfs web portal.

**Update**

[image]

Comment: Hi Patrick thanks for your answer. When I open **Source Control Explorer** I get message `Team Foundation Server is not your current Source Control plug-in. CLick here to set the current Source Conctrol plug-in.` (I am using git source control) - is it possible to do something like this when using git?

Comment: Unfortunately, you can't. You may have to view this in code of the repo from web portal.  Cause for now we can't view the source code of git as the way as source control explorer of TFVC. **It's not support.**

Comment: That is unfortunate - it seems like such a simple thing to do (view readme file) - if only TFS portal would recognise my readmes when saved in the project folder!